# How to skip certain indexes which are empty while iterating over the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

for eg. I have the following list:

```py
final=['feed', 'thed', 'og']
```

and I'm iterating over it as:

```py
count=0
number_of_character_to_print = 8
for i in range(len(final)):
    for j in final:
        if count>=number_of_character_to_print:
            break
        else:
            print(j[i],end="")
            count=count+1
    print()
```

the output is:

```
fto
ehg
eeIndexError: string index out of range
```

and an out of index error so is there a way to skip the empty index in a list and more to next column?

Comment: Why is there an empty space after the ```or```?

Comment: `for i in range(c):` What is `c`?

Comment: Fix your indentation, and syntax.

Comment: What's the value of `c`? If greater that `2` there you have it, `'og'` is only two chars long.

Comment: Also, what is ```k```?

Comment: There's no way that code gives that output, because it doesn't parse as valid python. Post your real code.

Comment: c=3,len(s)=8,k=0 initially in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either check the index before:

```
if len(j) > i:
    print(j[i],end="")
    k=k+1
```

or catch the index error:

```
try:
    print(j[i],end="")
    k=k+1
except IndexError:
    pass
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of k is, so I don't know if it belongs in the try/if blocks or outside them.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition before printing the character

```py
if k>=len(s) or :
    break
else:
    if i < len(j):
        print(j[i],end="")
    else:
        #Do something or just print a space or ignore this else
    k=k+1
```

If this didn't solve the problem we will need better example (explain what are the variable c,k,s and show an example of a full exepted output)